# Dynamic WPF Localization of Text bound to a view model Property

Tags: wpf, dynamic, localization

I'm working Localizing an existing project - need to focus only on localization, instead of changing the existing structure. I am using following Localization option: https://www.codinginfinity.me/posts/localization-of-a-wpf-app-the-simple-approach/

Below is my problem:
I have a Textblock bound to a property in view Model.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="DeviceCategoryValue" Grid.Row="1" 
                           Text = "{Binding DeviceCategory}" 
                           Height="22"
                           Margin="0,0,0,2">
```

In View Model, device category is set to some value, this is read from a hardware and varies with hardware connected type.

```
this.DeviceCategory = hwDevice.model.category; //**Imagine this value as "Category_1"**
```

Now I want to show *this.DeviceCategory* as a localized string.

Below code doesn't work as it searches for *DeviceCategory* in resx file. My resx file have *"Category_1"* as *Key* (which is the expected value of this.DeviceCategory)

```
 Text = "{loc:LocExtension DeviceCategory}"
```

How to get the value of DeviceCategory localized?